# varnishlog accessing POST body (varnish 4.x)

Tags: varnish

running **varnishd (varnish-4.1.0 revision 3041728)**, and logging using

```
varnishlog -q "BerespStatus >= 500"
```

I would like to know, if is possible to print POST content. There is XML-RPC service running on server and sometime it returns 500. In log is nothing, so I would like to know, which XMLRPC method is problematic.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Varnish (and hence varnishlog & varnishncsa) doesn't give you access to the http body in either the request or the response.  Therefore, this isn't possible using vanilla varnish.

Having said that, it is possible to [insert inline C](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-inline-c.html) code into your VCL.  Therefore, technically you could access the POST data using some custom C code and use [std.log](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/vmod_std.generated.html#func-log) to write the bits you care about to the logs.

It looks like there are some existing VMODs out there which access the POST data (eg [vmod_bodyaccess](https://github.com/aondio/libvmod-bodyaccess)), but you'd likely need to do more parsing than that to get the XML-RPC method out.

**Disclaimer**: I wouldn't recommend going anywhere near inline C unless you really know what you're doing.  Also, I've not tried any VMODs mentioned here, so can't tell how appropriate they are.